# how to confirm stripe payment and save to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

i am using nodeJS with mongoDB.

i am using a get request to load the checkout form and then a post request to create a paymentIntent and load the stripe checkout form. then the form is submitted using a javascript file on the checkout page which then sends the user to a success page if it was successful, where would be the best place to save the purchase to the database and update the user to add it to their purchases, if i do it on the post request, it is too early and saves it before the user has a chance to pay.

routes

```
router.get('/pay/:id', catchAsync (async(req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.flash('sir', 'you must be signed in')
        return res.redirect('/account/sign-in')
    }
    try{
    const { id } = req.params
    const  user  = req.user._id
    const concert =  await Concert.findById(id).populate('artist')
    const artistId = concert.artist
    const artist = await Artist.findById(artistId)
    const foundUser = await User.findById(user)
    const user_purchases = foundUser.purchased_content.toString()
    const concert_id = concert.id
    if(!concert || concert.artist.banned === 'true' || concert.visibility === 'private') {
        // return next(new AppError('page not found'))
        req.flash('paynf', 'sorry, the concert you are looking for could not be found')
    return res.redirect('/posts')
    }
    console.log(artist.stripe_id)
    res.render('pay', { concert, foundUser})
}catch(e){
    console.log(e.name)
    req.flash('paynf', 'sorry, the concert you are looking for could not be found')
    res.redirect('/posts')
}
 }))


 router.post('/pay/:id', catchAsync (async(req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
        req.flash('sir', 'you must be signed in')
        return res.redirect('/account/sign-in')
    }
    try{
    const { id } = req.params;
    const  user  = req.user._id
    const concert =  await Concert.findById(id).populate('artist')
    const concert_id = concert.id
    const artistId = concert.artist
    const artist = await Artist.findById(artistId)
    const stripe_id = artist.stripe_id
    const foundUser = await User.findById(user)
    if(!concert || concert.artist.banned === 'true' || concert.visibility === 'private') {
        // return next(new AppError('page not found'))
        req.flash('paynf', 'sorry, the concert you are looking for could not be found')
    return res.redirect('/posts')
    }
    const purchase = new Purchase(req.body)
    const customer = ({
        id: foundUser.cus_id,
        name: 'john',
        email: foundUser.email

    });

    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    customer: customer.id,
      amount: concert.price*100,
      description: `${concert.title} by ${concert.artName}`,
      currency: "gbp",
      receipt_email: customer.email,
      automatic_payment_methods: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      application_fee_amount: Math.round(concert.price*100*0.35),
      transfer_data: {
        destination: artist.stripe_id,
      },
    });
    res.send({
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    return res.send('/posts')
}}))
```

javascript for checkout page:

````
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51KJaaVEnftAKbusC8A9kTrtzrLKklZDHQdserQ2ZrYMHRqFRfbMk9SrGVnQlLoSjIfqmOCOEsDmcsTnO0evWY2Pr00nNd02KLv");



let elements;

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const response = await fetch(window.location.href, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ items }),
  });
  const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

  const appearance = {
    theme: 'stripe'
  }

  elements = stripe.elements({ appearance, clientSecret });

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}

async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      // Make sure to change this to your payment completion page
      return_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
      receipt_email: 'virtconcerts@gmail.com'
    },
  });

  // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
  // confirming the payment. Otherwise, your customer will be redirected to
  // your `return_url`. For some payment methods like iDEAL, your customer will
  // be redirected to an intermediate site first to authorize the payment, then
  // redirected to the `return_url`.
  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occured.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

// Fetches the payment intent status after payment submission
async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageText.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }}```
````

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on your customers being returned to the `return_url` following a successful payment to handle any fulfilment or post-payment requirements. Instead you should implement a [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to handle these actions.

Specifically, listen for the `payment_intent.succeeeded` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded). Details [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events).

Comment: thank you, i will take a look at these.

Comment: Hi , i have the same question, if we are using webhook, how can we retrieve the items to save in the database?

Comment: You'll need to make a subsequent request to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) the Checkout Session, and expand the `line_items` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items). That field is not returned as part of webhook event payloads.